# How to forward http request to multiple servers?

Tags: apache, tomcat

The problem is the following: There is one client C and servers A and B. The client sends information to server A, but server B should also receive this information to do additional work. I think there is an easy way to do this, but i dont know it. I dont want to touch code in client or server.

I use apache and tomcat.

So far I only discovered ways to redirect incoming requests to another url, so the relation is one->one. But I need one->many.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i try to achieve to forward the request from server A to server B, but let both process the request

Comment: You need some kind of logic to determine which traffic you should forward, and which traffic you should handle alone

Answer (score 1):

you probably need 3 servers, one with 3 nic and the other twoo with one. The first one shoud have a bonding on mode 3 (broadcast). It's a simple but expensive idea.

I don't know if you can get the same with IPTABLES rules or similar...